# RAML - how to design endpoints with parameters?

Tags: raml, raml-1.0

I have a requirement to design this spec using RAML:

```
Resource: quantity

Method: GET

URL: {orderId}/{itemId}/quantity
```

Objective is to pass orderId and itemId in the URI and get quantity. I am designing it this way:

```
/{orderId}/{itemId}/quantity:
  get:
```

Is it a best practice to design resource this way or there have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will be a bit more RESTful by providing the relationship between your orders and items as collections and individual data:

```
/orders:
  /{order_id}:
    /items:
      /{item_id}:
        get:
```

`quantity` should be a field in the response body.